# In-place run length decoding?

Tags: c, encoding, compression

Given a run length encoded string, say "A3B1C2D1E1", decode the string in-place.
The answer for the encoded string is "AAABCCDE". Assume that the encoded array is large enough to accommodate the decoded string, i.e. you may assume that the array size = MAX[length(encodedstirng),length(decodedstring)].

This does not seem trivial, since merely decoding A3 as 'AAA' will lead to over-writing 'B' of the original string.

Also, one cannot assume that the decoded string is always larger than the encoded string.
Eg: Encoded string - 'A1B1', Decoded string is 'AB'. Any thoughts?

And it will always be a letter-digit pair, i.e. you will not be asked to converted `0515` to `0000055555`

Comment: One suggestion would be to start your output at the end of the array and work backwards.

Comment: Please define "in-place" and the language to be used. This is trivial with a `preg_replace_callback` in PHP, which is about as "in-place" as you can get with languages at that level of abstraction.

Comment: By in-place, I mean not using another array to write the output. It is ok to use temporary variables. Language would be C/C++. @user1118321: That will not work since you can still over-write values of the original encoded string. Eg: "A1B1". Writing 'A' to the last position would over-write the '1' next to 'B'.

Comment: Right, but if you start from the end of the encoded string, you have less chance of that happening, depending on how large the output array is. So you'd decode B1 first, and put a "B" where the (second) 1 is. Then you'd decode A1, and put an "A" where the B is. There are still cases where it won't work if the array is only as long as the input string (which it can't be because the output can be larger than the input).

Comment: Here's a potential problem. Try `A1B3` in an array of length 4. If you start and the end, you overwrite the 1. Similarly the other way around with `A3B1`. That raises another question....

Comment: .. what *exactly* is the input to this question? You are given the encoded string *and* the length of the array. The array is long enough to hold the encoded string (obviously), and is long enough to hold the decoded string. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1118321: Doing what you said will fail for this case. Input "A3B1B1B1A3". Note that the decoded string is actually smaller than the encoded string. But the problem says that the array is "only as large" as MAX(length(encodedstring),length(decodedstring)). If I were to start working from the last 'A3'. It would wipe out the '1' of the last 'B'.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Bugaoo, I think the problem does not say the array is "only as large as ...". I think we're just told that the array is "at least as large as". I was under the impression that the array length was another input to the problem.

Comment: So the input could be "convert `A1B1` and the array is 100 chars long" ?

Comment: .. are we guaranteed that its always a letter-digit pair? i.e. we wouldn't have `0515 => 0000011111`? If so, we can easily ditch the `1`s as they can be interpreted as being redundant.

Comment: My bad. I should have read your comment more attentively. So, the problem is this. You are given an RLE string array. The goal is to decode this string. The array size is "not" another input to the program. You may assume that the array size = MAX[length(encodedstirng),length(decodedstring)].

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You are guaranteed the letter-digit pair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we don't already know, we should scan through first, adding up the digits, in order to calculate the length of the decoded string.

It will always be a letter-digit pair, hence you can delete the `1`s from the string without any confusion.

```
A3B1C2D1E1
```

becomes

```
A3BC2DE
```

Here is some code, in C++, to remove the `1`s from the string (O(n) complexity).

```
// remove 1s
int i = 0; // read from here
int j = 0; // write to here
while(i < str.length) {
    assert(j <= i); // optional check
    if(str[i] != '1') {
        str[j] = str[i];
        ++ j;
    }
    ++ i;
}
str.resize(j); // to discard the extra space now that we've got our shorter string
```

Now, this string is guaranteed to be shorter than, or the same length as, the final decoded string. We can't make that claim about the original string, but we can make it about this modified string.

(An optional, trivial, step now is to replace every `2` with the previous letter. `A3BCCDE`, but we don't need to do that).

Now we can start working from the end. We have already calculated the length of the decoded string, and hence we know exactly where the final character will be. We can simply copy the characters from the end of our short string to their final location.

During this copy process from right-to-left, if we come across a digit, we must make multiple copies of the letter that is just to the left of the digit. You might be worried that this might risk overwriting too much data. But we proved earlier that our encoded string, or any substring thereof, will never be longer than its corresponding decoded string; this means that there will always be enough space.

Comment: Excellent. This works. The only issue is that the removal of the '1's from the input takes O(n^2). But having said that, the question did not ask for a specific time complexity, so marking this as the "accepted answer" :). Thanks!

Comment: I think the `1`s can be removed on O(n). Just a moment, I'll update the answer with some relevant C code.

Comment: I've written O(n) code for that. The code for expanding the string will be a bit more complex, but the complexity should be linear again (linear in the size of the output)

Comment: Ah, but now this violates the "in-place" requirement. You are not allowed to use extra space.

Comment: @Bugaoo, that code for removing `1`s is in-place. The string is overwriting itself. See how the two pointers `without_ones` and `with_ones` point at the same string. (Maybe this is confusing if you're not familiar with the gory details of C.) I'll think about a clearer way to write the same algorithm.

Comment: @trinithis: I mentioned before why I accepted it. The question did not ask for a specific time complexity. Aaron's solution (without the remove 1's) did solve the problem in-place.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Brilliant, I get it now :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you have more than 9 consecutive characters. Example 11A12B will become A2B after the removal of 1 loop, how will you differentiate between 1A2B, 11A12B, 1A12B and all the other permutations?

Comment: The whole format has a maximum run length of 9 anyway unless you limit yourself to pure alphabet as repeat data. You can always encode 12 * `T` as `T9T4`. You can have much more range with binary RLE (where each count byte can have values up to 255), but even there, if you exceed the maximum you can store, the normal way to solve it is just to write a repeat code when you reach that max repeat value and then continue the process.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is `O(n)` and in-place. The algorithm should not access memory it shouldn't, both read and write. I did some debugging, and it appears correct to the sample tests I fed it.

---

High level overview:

- Determine the encoded length.
- Determine the decoded length by reading all the numbers and summing them up.
- End of buffer is MAX(decoded length, encoded length).
- Decode the string by starting from the end of the string. Write from the end of the buffer.
- Since the decoded length might be greater than the encoded length, the decoded string might not start at the start of the buffer. If needed, correct for this by shifting the string over to the start.

---

```
int isDigit (char c) {
    return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
}

unsigned int toDigit (char c) {
    return c - '0';
}

unsigned int intLen (char * str) {
    unsigned int n = 0;
    while (isDigit(*str++)) {
        ++n;
    }
    return n;
}

unsigned int forwardParseInt (char ** pStr) {
    unsigned int n = 0;
    char * pChar = *pStr;
    while (isDigit(*pChar)) {
        n = 10 * n + toDigit(*pChar);
        ++pChar;
    }
    *pStr = pChar;
    return n;
}

unsigned int backwardParseInt (char ** pStr, char * beginStr) {
    unsigned int len, n;
    char * pChar = *pStr;
    while (pChar != beginStr && isDigit(*pChar)) {
        --pChar;
    }
    ++pChar;
    len = intLen(pChar);
    n = forwardParseInt(&pChar);
    *pStr = pChar - 1 - len;
    return n;
}

unsigned int encodedSize (char * encoded) {
    int encodedLen = 0;
    while (*encoded++ != '\0') {
        ++encodedLen;
    }
    return encodedLen;
}

unsigned int decodedSize (char * encoded) {
    int decodedLen = 0;
    while (*encoded++ != '\0') {
        decodedLen += forwardParseInt(&encoded);
    }
    return decodedLen;
}

void shift (char * str, int n) {
    do {
        str[n] = *str;
    } while (*str++ != '\0');
}

unsigned int max (unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

void decode (char * encodedBegin) {
    int shiftAmount;
    unsigned int eSize = encodedSize(encodedBegin);
    unsigned int dSize = decodedSize(encodedBegin);
    int writeOverflowed = 0;
    char * read = encodedBegin + eSize - 1;
    char * write = encodedBegin + max(eSize, dSize);
    *write-- = '\0';
    while (read != encodedBegin) {
        unsigned int i;
        unsigned int n = backwardParseInt(&read, encodedBegin);
        char c = *read;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            *write = c;
            if (write != encodedBegin) {
                write--;
            }
            else {
                writeOverflowed = 1;
            }
        }
        if (read != encodedBegin) {
            read--;
        }
    }
    if (!writeOverflowed) {
        write++;
    }
    shiftAmount = encodedBegin - write;
    if (write != encodedBegin) {
        shift(write, shiftAmount);
    }
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    //char buff[256] = { "!!!A33B1C2D1E1\0!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" };
    char buff[256] = { "!!!A2B12C1\0!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" };
    //char buff[256] = { "!!!A1B1C1\0!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" };
    char * str = buff + 3;
    //char buff[256] = { "A1B1" };
    //char * str = buff;
    decode(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For test case "A3B1B1B1A3". Length of encoded string = 10. Decoded string is "AAABBBAAA". Length of decoded string is "9". If I were to decode the string from the end (i.e right-to-left), decoding the last 'A3' would over-write my string array. This is because there is no guarantee that the length of the decoded string is greater than the length of the encoded string.

Comment: An even simpler example of this problem is `A1B3`, which decodes to `ABBB`. Both these strings are of length 4. There is not sufficient space to shift the rest of the string to the left. @trinithis, Are you proposing that, after processing `B3`, then string should be `A1BBB`? This is a 5 character word.

Comment: Might be possible to temporarily use the spot the null character sits in. Not sure if that covers all the bases for this bug. I'll think about it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question, though it's not particularly difficult if you think about it. As you say, decoding `A3` as `AAA` and just writing it in place will overwrite the chars `B` and `1`, so why not just move those farther along the array first?

For instance, once you've read `A3`, you know that you need to make space for one extra character, if it was `A4` you'd need two, and so on. To achieve this you'd find the end of the string in the array (do this upfront and store it's index).

Then loop though, moving the characters to their new slots:

To start: `A|3|B|1|C|2|||||||`
Have a variable called `end` storing the index 5, i.e. the last, non-blank, entry.

You'd read in the first pair, using a variable called `cursor` to store your current position - so after reading in the `A` and the `3` it would be set to 1 (the slot with the 3).

Pseudocode for the move:

var n = array[cursor] - 2; // n = 1, the 3 from A3, and then minus 2 to allow for the pair.

for(i = end; i > cursor; i++)
{
  array[i + n] = array[i];
}

This would leave you with:

`A|3|A|3|B|1|C|2|||||`

Now the `A` is there once already, so now you want to write `n + 1` `A`'s starting at the index stored in `cursor`:

```
for(i = cursor; i < cursor + n + 1; i++)
{
  array[i] = array[cursor - 1];
}

// increment the cursor afterwards!
cursor += n + 1;
```

Giving:

`A|A|A|A|B|1|C|2|||||`

Then you're pointing at the start of the next pair of values, ready to go again. I realise there are some holes in this answer, though that is intentional as it's an interview question! For instance, in the edge cases you specified `A1B1`, you'll need a different loop to move subsequent characters backwards rather than forwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "move farthest along" but if you mean to write the output from the end of the array, that will still lead to over-writes. Eg - Consider "A1B1". Writing 'A' to the end would over-write the '1' next to 'B' (if this is what you meant).

Comment: This isn't really an "in-place" algorithm, since you need O(n) auxiliary storage for the array of endpoints.

Comment: I'm talking about using 1 variable to store the current position, one to store the number of places to move, and one to store the current end position — how is that O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

Another O(n^2) solution follows.

Given that there is no limit on the complexity of the answer, this simple solution seems to work perfectly.

```
while ( there is an expandable element ):
    expand that element
    adjust (shift) all of the elements on the right side of the expanded element
```

Where:

- Free space size is the number of empty elements left in the array.
- An expandable element is an element that:

  ```
  expanded size - encoded size <= free space size
  ```

The point is that in the process of reaching from the run-length code to the expanded string, at each step, there is at least
one element that can be expanded (easy to prove).